# C++ function pointer with templates

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to store a pointer to a member function. The class that needs to store the pointer is declared as:

```
template <typename TDataType, typename T>
bool my_function(std::string topic_name,
                 void(T::*)(const TDataType&) fp,
                 T* obj)
```

I get the error:

```
error: expected ',' or '...' before 'fp'
                               void(T::*)(const TDataType&) fp,
```

Can someone tell me what's going on? Looks like it's a syntax error that I don't get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for a member function pointer is

```
return_type(class_name::* function_pointer_name)(function_parameters)
```

So

```
template <typename TDataType, typename T>
bool my_function(std::string topic_name,
                 void(T::*)(const TDataType&) fp,
                 T* obj)
```

Needs to be

```
template <typename TDataType, typename T>
bool my_function(std::string topic_name,
                 void(T::* fp)(const TDataType&)'
                 T* obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
void(T::*)(const TDataType&) fp
```

to

```
void(T::* fp)(const TDataType&)
```